# Fatal Error running Ngrok on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ngrok

I have installed ngrok using:

```
wget https://dl.ngrok.com/ngrok_2.0.15_linux_arm.zip

unzip https://dl.ngrok.com/ngrok_2.0.15_linux_arm.zip
```

And run it with

```
./ngrok 80
```

but this returns errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ./ngrok
runtime: g1: leftover defer argp=0x1091b660 pc=0x2d837c
        defer 0x10936100 argp=0x1091b660 pc=0x2d837c
        defer 0x10936000 argp=0x1091b7c4 pc=0x6b4f8
fatal error: traceback has leftover defers

runtime stack:
runtime.gothrow(0x54d3c0, 0x1d)
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/panic.go:503 +0x84
runtime.gentraceback(0x2d8118, 0x1091b5f4, 0x91930, 0x109000a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7fffffff, 0xbef42770, 0xbef42778, 0x0, ...)
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/traceback.go:445 +0x6bc
copystack(0x109000a0, 0x1000)
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/stack.c:623 +0xfc
runtime.newstack()
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/stack.c:789 +0x444
runtime.morestack()
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:319 +0x4c

goroutine 1 [stack growth, locked to thread]:
gopkg.in/stack%2ev1.func·001()
        /Users/aes/src/ngrok/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/stack.v1/stack.go:193 fp=0x1091b5f4 sp=0x1091b5f4
runtime.call16(0x1094ee6c, 0x1093611c, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:406 +0x70 fp=0x1091b608 sp=0x1091b5f4
runtime.gopanic(0x4917e8, 0x1090a020)
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/panic.go:387 +0x3b4 fp=0x1091b640 sp=0x1091b608
runtime.panicdivide()
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/panic.go:24 +0x54 fp=0x1091b654 sp=0x1091b640
gopkg.in/stack%2ev1.func·002(0x0)
        /Users/aes/src/ngrok/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/stack.v1/stack.go:208 +0xc4 fp=0x1091b674 sp=0x1091b654
gopkg.in/stack%2ev1.findSigpanic(0x0)
        /Users/aes/src/ngrok/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/stack.v1/stack.go:209 +0x58 fp=0x1091b688 sp=0x1091b674
gopkg.in/stack%2ev1.init()
        /Users/aes/src/ngrok/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/stack.v1/stack.go:213 +0x74 fp=0x1091b694 sp=0x1091b688
main.init()
        /Users/aes/src/ngrok/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/web_ui.go:466 +0x64 fp=0x1091b7c0 sp=0x1091b694
runtime.main()
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/proc.go:58 +0xf8 fp=0x1091b7e4 sp=0x1091b7c0
runtime.goexit()
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:1322 +0x4 fp=0x1091b7e4 sp=0x1091b7e4

goroutine 4 [runnable]:
runtime.runfinq()
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/malloc.go:712
runtime.goexit()
        /Users/aes/src/gonative/_go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:1322 +0x4
```

I can get `v1.7` to work but `v2.0.15` doesn't seem to work however I can't find a way to authenticate  v1.7` with my authentication code from the ngrok website.

v2.0.15 seems to work fine on windows but not on raspberry pi B+.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Solved by clicking restore ngrok1.0 in admin to get a ngrok1.0 auth code. v2.0.15 still no longer works on raspberry pi

Comment: I'm working on fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was resolved in ngrok 2.0.16